# C# UWP Background color not filling all the way

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

In my MainPage.xaml I have a Grid.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <views:SidePage Grid.Column="0" />
        <views:ContentPage Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

The amount of spaces each page takes is correct but the Background color of the ContentPage doesn't match the width it takes.

[image]

This is the ContentPage.xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="MediaPlayer.Views.ContentPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Testing"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    
</Page>
```

And this is where I set the Background

```
public ContentPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Background = new SolidColorBrush(StaticColors.ContentBackgroundColor);
}
```

```
        public static readonly Color ContentBackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(150, 0, 0, 60);
```

As you can see "Testing" is on the white part.

Comment: Wrap `StackPanel` with a`Grid`. Looks like it doesn't respect the parent's width.

Comment: Wrapping the StackPanel with a Grid in ContentPage doesn't change it. Wrapping the Grid in MainPage with a StackPanel also doesn't work. The Background color doesn't match the width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fixed it**

I fixed it by wrapping the ContentPage in a separate Grid.

This is the new MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="MediaPlayer.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:views="using:MediaPlayer.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <views:SidePage Grid.Column="0" />
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <views:ContentPage />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

[image]